# .NET Label.TextAlign seems not to work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a label that I want to right align to be able to place aligned to a text box.
The Designer in Visual Studio 2010 Express have generated this code for me

```
this.lblAddData.AutoSize = true;  
this.lblAddData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(167, 452);  
this.lblAddData.Name = "lblAddData";  
this.lblAddData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 14);  
this.lblAddData.TabIndex = 5;  
this.lblAddData.Text = "text";  
this.lblAddData.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

[text][textbox]
In the code I change the text programmaticly

```
lblAddData.Text = "a very long text";
```

but the text is hiding behind the texbox that I have placed next to the label on the
right side.

[a ver][textbox]

Have someone experienced the same problem before?
I know it is missing information so ask me if you need more info.
Best Regards
Görgen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I spotted  the error myself; AutoSize was set to true, that is default behavour

```
this.lblAddData.AutoSize = true;
```

When I changed this to false it worked as I assumed it should.

Answer (score 3):

The [`TextAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.textalign.aspx) property controls how the text is aligned within the label:

> Gets or sets the alignment of text in the label.

If you change the length of the text you need recalculate the [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) of the label which is always top left.

I've found this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/LabelWithDivider.aspx) which, while probably over the top for what you want, states:

> Moreover, if you are going to change the label text (e.g., when localizing the application) or text alignment, **you'll have to resize/reposition controls**. Therefore, I have created this simple label that takes care of such details.

(my bold)

So you could use the same algorithm to reposition your label.

Comment: /facepalm   Really Microsoft? Really?